# How does DFS produce MST and All pairs shortest paths in unweighted graphs?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, graph-traversal

I was reading *Application of DFS* from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applications-of-depth-first-search/) where I came to a statement which I cannot really understand. Would anybody mind explaining this to me.

> For an unweighted graph, DFS traversal of the graph produces the minimum spanning tree and all pair shortest path tree.

*My doubt*: Is there anything  "Minimum spanning tree" for unweighted graph. I mean after all it is unweighted so what is sense of MST here? And I completely don't understand how DFS produces all pair shortest path. Would anybody mind elaborating this a bit.

Comment: Every spanning tree is an MST for unweighted graphs.

Comment: Have you read the comments? Multiple readers have expressed doubt in item 1) (even though not many give any reasoning).

Answer (score 4):

There are two claims here.

> For an unweighted graph, DFS traversal of the graph produces the minimum spanning tree.

This is true; in unweighted graphs, *every* spanning tree is minimal since they all have the same number of edges, $n-1$.

A nitpick I'd have is "the"; they should write "*a* minimum spanning tree".

> For an unweighted graph, DFS traversal of the graph produces the all pair shortest path tree.

This is false, it doesn't even produce a single-source shortest path tree. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/why-cant-dfs-be-used-to-find-shortest-paths-in-unweighted-graphs).

In general, an APSP tree *may not even exist*. There are $n(n-1)$ shortest paths to encode, and it would be quite the coincidence if they shared only $n-1$ edges. Which *can* happen, e.g. in acyclic graphs, but it is certainly not always true. I'll leave it to you to come up with a small counter example.

Answer (score 2):

*Unweighted* in your blog post is probably a typo for *undirected*. However, even under this interpretation the blog post is wrong. See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/depth-first-search-to-find-minimum-spanning-tree) regarding DFS and minimum spanning tree, for example.

Don't take blog posts too seriously.